# JS: Create a method to return an array that does not include the index values from the array passed to my method

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, filter

I am trying to create a method that is added to the Array.prototype object.  The objective is to return an array that does not include the index values from the array passed to my method.

Below are my test specs.

```
describe('doNotInclude', () => {
  it('the doNotInclude method is added to the Array.prototype object', () => {
    expect(typeof Array.prototype.doNotInclude).toBe('function');
  });
  it('returns an array', () => {
    expect(Array.isArray([1, 2, 3, 4].doNotInclude(3))).toBe(true);
    expect(Array.isArray([1, 2, 3, 4].doNotInclude([0, 2]))).toBe(true);
  });
  it('does not include the index values from the array passed to `doNotInclude`', () => {
    expect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].doNotInclude([3, 4])).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
    expect(
      ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'].doNotInclude([
        0,
        1,
      ])
    ).toEqual(['two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']);
```

My code is below:

```
Array.prototype.doNotInclude = function (arr){
    return this.filter((elem, index) => {
      if (!arr.includes(index)){
        return elem; 
      }
    })
  }
```

My code does not pass any of the specs.  What am I doing wrong?

Also to check my conceptual understanding, the filter method is run on which array?  Is it the one containing indexes?

Comment: You want a method that takes a given array and removes values that match the values of the array in the second parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a method that takes a given array and removes values that match the values of the array passed as parameter. This demo will return the indexes of the array that values did not match the values of the array passed in. This is possible by the newest array method `.flatMap()` which essentially is `.map()` and `.flat()` methods combined. The mapping part will run a function on each value just as `.map()` does but the difference is that each return is an an array:

```
 array.map(function(x) { return x});
 array.flatMap(function(x) { return [x]});
```

If you wish to remove a value you return an empty array:

```
  array.map(function(x) { return x}).filter(function(x) { return x !== z}); 
  array.flatMap(function(x) { return x !== z ? [x] : []});
```

By using a ternary control you are able to directly remove values rather than indirectly by `.filter()`.

> ```
>   if x does not equal z return [x] else return empty array []
> ```

```
    return x !== z ? [x] : []
```

The result is then flattened into a normal array.

```js
Array.prototype.exclude = function(array) {
  return this.flatMap((value, index) => {
    return array.includes(value) ? [] : [index];
  })
}

let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

let z = x.exclude([3, 4]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(z));
```

Comment: thank you; what does this line of code do?  return array.includes(value) ? [] : [index];

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't want to `return elem` you want to return a boolean that indicates wether `elem` should be included or not.

2) `doNotInclude(3)` indicates that `arr` might not be an array. You have to check that with `Array.isArray(arr)` and change the logic accordingly (compare the index against `arr` directly).